# An error occurred with torch_scatter while executing a graph generation model

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I'm having an error while executing the EDGE diffusion model for graph generation. In particular the error is related to `torch_scatter`. Here the details:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/turex/Desktop/graph-generation-EDGE/train.py", line 3, in <module>
    from diffusion.utils import add_parent_path, set_seeds
  File "/Users/turex/Desktop/graph-generation-EDGE/diffusion/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .diffusion_base import *
  File "/Users/turex/Desktop/graph-generation-EDGE/diffusion/diffusion_base.py", line 5, in <module>
    from torch_scatter import scatter
  File "/Users/turex/Desktop/graph-generation-EDGE/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch_scatter/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    torch.ops.load_library(spec.origin)
  File "/Users/turex/Desktop/graph-generation-EDGE/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_ops.py", line 933, in load_library
    ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Users/turex/Desktop/graph-generation-EDGE/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch_scatter/_version_cpu.so, 0x0006): Symbol not found: __ZN3c1017RegisterOperatorsD1Ev
```

I've tried to install different versions of both `torch` and `torch_scatter`, but I cannot understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the fact that either `pytorch` or `pytorch-scatter` were installed via different channels like `conda-forge` and `pytorch`. I solved the problem by creating a fresh environment, and including `pytorch` from `pytorch` channel and `pytorch-scatter` from `pyg` channel. Everything now is working perfectly.